# How to programmatically change style in an ADF table

Tags: java, jdeveloper

I got an ADF table generated form my data controls.
But I need to change the style of every cell in my backing bean.
I can't really find anything useful on google, hopefully you can provide me with some useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you be a bit more specific? Which jdev version? If you need to change each cell why not using a skin?

Based on the comments we now know that you use jdev 11.1.2.2.0. 
What you can do is to bind the styleClass property of the table to a backing bean property. The property in the bean has a getter and a setter method. In the setter method you can get all the values you need from the row and do you calculation. Based on the outcome you return the name of a style class suitable for the cell. The different style classes you define in a skin fro the application.
If you e.g. defien the following style classes in your skin

```
.high_value { background-color:green; }
.negative_value { background-color:red;}
```

and in a bean in request scope, which you access from the page the table is on

```
    private String styleForCell;

public String getStyleForCell()
{
    // get the value of the cell
    FacesContext lContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext lELContext = lContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory lExpressionFactory = lContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    Number val;
    val = (Number) lExpressionFactory.createValueExpression(lELContext, "#{row.valargument}", Object.class).getValue(lELContext);
    if (val == null)
        return "";

    // do the calculation and return the suitable style class
    int ival = val.intValue();
    if (ival >= 100000 )
        return "high_value";
    else if (ival < 0)
        return "negative_value";
    else 
        return "";         
}

public void setStyleForCell(String aStyleForCell)
{
    this.styleForCell = aStyleForCell;
}
```

Now you can access the calculated style class from the tables column styleClass property as #{beanname.styleForCell} 
This will call the method for each cell of the column.

Comment: I need check the data of every cell in the table and if has a particularly value, the value in that cell needs to be bold and an other color.

Comment: I outlined a solution in my answer

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional EL in your field's inlineStyle to set the style based on the value.
Something like #{binding.value > 1000 ? 'font=bold' : 'font=regular'}

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the particullar value (in your example 1000). That's why I need to do it in my bean because I need to get the ID from the selected row, get the corresponding data from my webservice and then check the value of each cell and if needed, change the style.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on the previous answer. Note that the way you change the cell coloring pretty much depends on the use case. If your use case requires dynamic ad-hoc color coding then the answer is different as if the requirement is to change color coding to implement a corporate branding

Frank

Comment: I need to compare the data in my table to data from webservice. When the data is different, the value of that cell needs to be in bold and a red (or other) color.